# How to fill empty space produced by margins of the inner elements with the background of the parent element?

Tags: css

In the example http://jsfiddle.net/cq7fkkdx/1/ :

```
<div style="background-color: #AAA;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
</div>
<div style="background-color: #EAA;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
</div>
```

It produces 2 blocks with space between them. The space is the result of the first p-tag. Actually I was expecting that the first div would be higher to cover the bottom margin of the paragraph, but instead it produces the space before the next paragraph.

How to tell the first div that its background should also cover the bottom margin of the inner paragraph? (Both divs should connect)

Comment: Don't use margins then, use padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `padding` instead of `margin` on the `<p>` tag. Here's an example:

```css
p {
  margin: 0px 0px;
  padding: 1em 0em;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #AAA;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
</div>
<div style="background-color: #EAA;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cq7fkkdx/2/)**.

**UPDATE:**

Since you don't want to remove the margins from `<p>`, adding `overflow: hidden` to the `<div>` containing the `<p>` tag will solve the issue.

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #AAA;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
</div>
<div style="background-color: #EAA;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cq7fkkdx/4/)**.

Comment: I don't want to destroy the standard p-layout. Margin should stay margin.